# Don't displayed custom error page on jsp

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, error-code

I wan't to displey own 404 page. in web.xml i defined

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/error404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

In my filter I throw this error the next way:

```
response.sendError(404);
System.out.println("telst log: 404");
```

In logs i see my log, but page doest displayed correctly. Brouser print

```
Oops! This link appears to be broken.
```

But when I look at source code of the page, there is html code of my page!!!

Could enybody help ?
Thanks.

brouser : crome , IE. Server  - JBoss 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404#Custom_error_pages and http://www.thesitewizard.com/webdesign/google-chrome.shtml. IE and Chrome replace the custom page by their own 404 page if the custom page is less than 512 bytes.

Comment: Thanks a lot) I have killed a looot of time.